# tabBarOnPress stopped working react-navigation 3.3.2

Tags: react-navigation

After upgrading to react-navigation 3.3.2 the tabBarOnPress no longer fires. Code snippet below.  Any ideas?

```
const Tabs = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    HomeStack,
    WallStack,
    MemeStack,
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
      tabBarOnPress: () => {
        console.log('tab pressed');
      }
    })

  }
);

export default DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator({
  Tabs: Tabs
},{
  drawerBackgroundColor: Colors.grayDark,
  contentComponent: Sidebar
})
```

Comment: Are you having this issue using reacr-navigation with react-native?  I had the same issue on reac-native when developing using the Expo client on iOS.  For some unexplained reason, maybe due to timing within the Expo client in debugger mode, the tabBarOnLongPress was called instead of tabBarOnPress.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`tabBarOnPress` is working, but I'm using it like this. You need to pass it as a property of each stack. (don't forget to call the `defaultHandler` to keep the default behavior:

```js
const DashboardStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Dashboard,
  }
);

DashboardStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarOnPress({ navigation, defaultHandler }) {
    // do something
    defaultHandler();
  },
};

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile,
    AccountInfo,
    Membership,
    Browser,
    ConnectedAccounts,
  }
);

ProfileStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarOnPress({ navigation, defaultHandler }) {
    // do something
    defaultHandler();
  },
};

const SpendingStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Budget,
    Transactions,
  }
);

SpendingStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarOnPress({ navigation, defaultHandler }) {
    // do something
    defaultHandler();
  },
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    SpendingStack,
    DashboardStack,
    ProfileStack,
  }
);
```